# How to suppress GCC Errors or suppress specific errors via makefile

Tags: linux, gcc, centos, gcc-warning

So when running my makefile I link 32bit and 64bit libraries and if 32 isn't present it gives me an error I was wondering if there was a way to filter out this error via using a flag on the makefile or if there is a way to suppress this error via GCC flag.

```
Linking 32 bit
gcc: error: vdbjni.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: vdblinux.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: vdb_dv.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: vdb.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: chmod.o: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access ‘/root/vdbenchsource/linux/linux32.so’: No such file or directory
```